# Is it a good practise to update or insert into a table using SSRS report?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a task where I need to get inputs from user and perform some updates to the DB table. Now I knwo this is something needs to be done through a UI, but due to some limitations  I have been assigned a task to do this through SSRS report. I know this is possible to do but is it a good practise to do updates or insert through a SSRS report?

Comment: If this it the sort of task that gets assigned to you at you current place of employment, then consider a job somewhere else where they may be doing things properly. This is a hack if I have ever heard of one.

Comment: This is the kind of requirement that you push back strongly on. This is not the right tool.

Answer (score 4):

First, SSRS is not designed for this kind of thing and, May be someone who has done this, I would advise you consider an Access Form against a SQL back-end, Sharepoint or an ASP.NET web form

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Zaynul, this is not good practice.  Interface wise, user expectation from reports is not that it causes updates or inserts, but retrieves data. Report automation tools (largely out of your control) like subscriptions could have this running in a way you don't want. It's probably being used as a substitute from writing an Interface element in a "program".  Finally, lack of control of the parameter fields makes validating inputs more painful (compare with say, VB).  If the drawbacks are unclear to you, you should probably avoid this path altogether.

If you need to do something like this bear in mind the drawbacks and take precautions

1. Confirmation parameters "Update? Y/N"
2. Preview what will be updated or inserted before allowing an update
3. Is there a way to "reverse" the update or insert
4. Is the change stored so there is an audit trail for changes done this way
5. Follow the same rules you'd use if you wrote a real interface/program for updates